# Physical keyboard layout is reset with every reboot

Tags: settings, keyboard, external-keyboard, lenovo-yoga

In my Yoga BOOK, which comes with a physical keboard like a laptop, I have to set the layout of the physical keyboard every time I reboot the device. How to keep the settings?

How I set it: Settings, Languages and Input, Physical keyboard, The individual keyboard apps (it forgets the layout of all of them).

Android 7.1.1